# Why does $\rho(n) = \rho(1 + \dots + 1) = \rho(1)^n$. where $\rho$ is a homomorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory, group-homomorphism

I am studying representation theory, and below is an excerpt from my lecture notes.

> Suppose that $G = (\Bbb Z,+)$. Then, if $\rho$ is a representation of $G$, it is completely determined by $V$ and the invertible linear map $\rho(1) : V\to V$ (which can be anything). This is because we then have $$\rho(n) = \rho(1 + \dots + 1) = \rho(1)^n.$$ Thus a representation of $\Bbb Z$ is just a vector space $V$ together with an invertible linear map from $V$ to itself.

I am confused as to the middle line, where $\rho(n) = \rho(1 + \dots + 1) = \rho(1)^n$. I would have thought that $\rho(n) = \rho(1 + \dots + 1) = \rho(1) + \dots + \rho(1) = n\rho(1).$ Why is this as so? Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Why? Because linear operator composition is written multiplicatively. $f=\rho(1)$, Then $f\circ f=f^2$ and not $f+f$.

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 2):

The elements of the codomain are just written multiplicatively (because they're functions).